# Bitmap not acting properly within a loop

Tags: c#, loops, draw

I am trying to get a bitmap to bounce off the top and bottom of a Window. Which seems to be working fine. The Draw method shown is being called within a loop, leading to the bitmap to be constantly redrawn with its new position.

```
public class Ball
{
double SpeedX = 4;
double SpeedY = 4;
int ballWidth = 1;
public double X {get; private set;}
public double Y {get; private set;}

public void Draw(Window screen)
{
    X += SpeedX;
    Y += SpeedY;
    if (Y <= 0) {
        SpeedY = -SpeedY;
        Y = 0;    
    }
   
    else if (Y >= (screen.Height - ballWidth)) {      
        SpeedY = -SpeedY;
        Y = screen.Height - ballWidth;
    }
    Bitmap.Draw(X,Y);
}
}
```

However, I am trying to change the initial values SpeedX and Speedy when the bitmap is created. When I pass these values in, my bitmap get stuck on the Top/Bottom of the window - SpeedY appears to result in 0, whereas SpeedX continues to work (leading to the bitmap to slide across the Top/Bottom of the screen). Is there something I'm doing wrong? I don't see why passing in two values from outside would be messing up the Draw function.

```
public Ball RandomBall(Window game)
    { 
        Ball newball = new Ball(_Game);
        Random direction = new Random();
        
        newball.SpeedX = 5;
        newball.SpeedY = 5;

        return newball;
```

Comment: This is propbably not related to your problem, but I think that `Y` must be set to `ballWidth` and not 0 in the first `if` (and the first `if` should test on `ballWidth and not 0)

Comment: Cheers, I just changed that. Didn't solve the issue however.